# Finding the length of the opposite and adjacent sides of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I am writing a small game in javascript. It's been a while since I have done any basic maths and I can't get some of my positioning to work properly. Apologies if this question is too simple, but I can't spot my error.

I have the following code

```
var xPos = 0, yPos = 0, angle = 45, distance = 1;

var yDelta = Math.sin(angle) * distance,
    xDelta = Math.sqrt((distance * distance) -(yDelta * yDelta));
yPos += yDelta;
xPos += xDelta;
```

- Starting at coordinate (0,0)
- Move 1 step at 45 degrees
- To get the new coordinates I need to get the distance moved up

  - As sin(theta) = opposite/hypotenuse this should be sin(theta) * hypotenuse
- And the distance moved across

  - As this is a right angled triangle this should mean hypotenuse squared - opposite (that we calculated in the previous step) squared.

This gives me (0.5253, 0.8509), but [this calculator](http://www.cleavebooks.co.uk/scol/calrtri.htm) tells me that it should be 0.7071 for each side. Can anyone explain what's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: "Opposite sides of a triangle"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put angle in radians, $sin(45) = sin(\pi /4) = 0.707$ (y coordinate)

$cos(\pi /4) = 0.707$ (x coordinate)

const $ \pi = 3.1415926$

Answer (score 1):

The calculator is right. I guess the problem is that your script thinks $45$ is an angle in radians, where it is in degrees. To solve that problem, multiply by $\frac{2\pi}{360}$ to get the angle in radians.